# return client socket.io to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

On the docs page they say that i need to use like this.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

there is any way to expose the client to a variable?

```
var socket = io.on('connection');
socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
```

On the help page they say that `Server#onconnection(socket:engine#Socket):Server` expose a client, but i can't figure out how to use it. [doc](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#onconnection(socket:engine#socket):server)

this way i can use socket inside my other functions.

Right now on every function that i emiting stuff i do the `io.on('connection', function (socket)` all over again

Another question:

There is a way to different files emit event to each other

app.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

file1.html emit

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost');

    socket.emit('event15', function(x){
    });

</script>
```

file2.html receive

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost');

    socket.on('event15', function(x){
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server you have to deal with multiple sockets, one for each client. That's why on the server, you write an event handler that sets up the socket for each new client that connects. The basic idea is this:

**Server:**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
```

All of your message handling is supposed to be setup in the outer function. If you want to use the socket elsewhere however, you can pass it on like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('login', function(data) {
    myServer.attemptLogin(socket, data.user, data.hash);
  });
});
```

The `attemptLogin(socket, user, hash)` function can now process the parameters, then reply to the client by calling `socket.emit()`

If you want to store each user's socket in a variable, you need to create a data structure to do that. Here's an example:

```
var users = {}; // empty object
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  users[socket.id] = socket; // store socket for later use
  // ...
});
```

This is only useful though if a connected user can somehow resume their previous session after a disconnect. Otherwise this is just a question of properly organizing your functions and variables.

As for the second question, you cannot send data from one HTML document to another. As soon as the user clicks a link leading to `file2.html`, a new socket will be opened and socket.io won't even realize that this is still the same user. As far as socket.io is concerned, some random dude just opened `file2.html` elsewhere in the world.
There are two ways around this: you can create a single-page app, where the user never actually navigates to another site. However they will still lose the connection if they accidentally close the tab, or navigate back, or refresh the page.
The other way is to use some kind of session information. If the user logs in, you can simply store their username and password hash in localStorage. On each page, check localStorage for the stored credentials, then send a `"login"` message to the server.

Comment: It helped clarify some things, but i don't care about users, there will be no "users" i just need to send and emit events, don't care if is for 2 or a thousand.
Almost nothing will be proccessed on the server, only on the clients.
Thats why I want to emit from file1 and react from file2.

Comment: Then why are you using socket.io at all? If you want to store information on file1 and read it back on file2, just use `localStorage`.

Comment: i don't said 'store', i said send events, pc 1 open file1 (admin page) send event, pc 2 file2 (front end) react to event and vice versa @chris-g (the third pc will be the server)

Comment: In that case the server has to relay the message. Exactly as shown in the very first code piece I posted. When a socket sends something, call `io.emit()` to send it to all connected sockets. I'm not sure what the problem is, all you need is to add the client socket code to both file1 and file2.

Comment: for some magic way i thought that i can send events client to client, without pass on the server, it's working now, i also was trying to socket.emit insted of io.emit and was falling out of scope. thanks a lot